# Google Cloud vision API usage to extract the text from image/pdf

Tags: spring-boot, csv, pdf, ocr, google-cloud-vision

I am working on the project where i have a data in the form of jpg image (i do have the same copy in pdf) and i was trying to convert the pdf to csv but it was not successfully converting all the data as i got some non-readable characters. Because if this pdf is in english then i am able to convert to csv successfully somehow but if its in utf-8 characters (Indian language) then i was having the problem to convert. So the next option that i tried is OCR cloud vision api which was provided by google. I am able to extract the text from this attached image successfully regardless of engligh or utf-8 character but its converting the extracted text to row is seems to be complex. i do not know whether we have any api to read the table of contents.

[image]

This is the actual image in English but i have the same data in utf-8 as well.  When i use the cloud vision api, i get the below result (note: i tried with the future type DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION and TEXT_DETECTION).

```
[
    {
        "mid_": "",
        "locale_": "en",
        "description_": "Page:1\nSI.No\nName of the agent\nIncentive\nAmt\nExecutive\n|1111 Main street -\nJames mart, Sales executive)\n1112 Main street -\n|Cameron mart, Sales executive)\n1\n200001\n2\n50001\nAgent\n1113 Main street -\nJames mart, Internal agent\n|(Comercial devision)\n1114 Main street
-\nCameron mart, Sales executive)\n1000\n3\n1500\n",
        "score_": 0,
        "confidence_": 0,
        "topicality_": 0,
        "boundingPoly_": {
            "vertices_": [
                {
                    "x_": 25,
                    "y_": 31,
                    "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
                    "unknownFields": {
                        "fields": {},
                        "fieldsDescending": {}
                    },
                    "memoizedSize": -1,
                    "memoizedHashCode": 0
                },
                {
                    "x_": 690,
                    "y_": 31,
                    "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
                    "unknownFields": {
                        "fields": {},
                        "fieldsDescending": {}
                    },
                    "memoizedSize": -1,
                    "memoizedHashCode": 0
                },
                {
                    "x_": 690,
                    "y_": 457,
                    "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
                    "unknownFields": {
                        "fields": {},
                        "fieldsDescending": {}
                    },
                    "memoizedSize": -1,
                    "memoizedHashCode": 0
                },
                {
                    "x_": 25,
                    "y_": 457,
                    "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
                    "unknownFields": {
                        "fields": {},
                        "fieldsDescending": {}
                    },
                    "memoizedSize": -1,
                    "memoizedHashCode": 0
                }
            ],
            "normalizedVertices_": [],
            "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
            "unknownFields": {
                "fields": {},
                "fieldsDescending": {}
            },
            "memoizedSize": -1,
            "memoizedHashCode": 0
        },
        "locations_": [],
        "properties_": [],
        "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
        "unknownFields": {
            "fields": {},
            "fieldsDescending": {}
        },
        "memoizedSize": -1,
        "memoizedHashCode": 0
    },
    {
        "mid_": "",
        "locale_": "",
        "description_": "Page:1",
        "score_": 0,
        "confidence_": 0,
        "topicality_": 0,
        "boundingPoly_": {
            "vertices_": [
                {
                    "x_": 631,
                    "y_": 32,
                    "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
                    "unknownFields": {
                        "fields": {},
                        "fieldsDescending": {}
                    },
                    "memoizedSize": -1,
                    "memoizedHashCode": 0
                },
                {
                    "x_": 690,
                    "y_": 31,
                    "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
                    "unknownFields": {
                        "fields": {},
                        "fieldsDescending": {}
                    },
                    "memoizedSize": -1,
                    "memoizedHashCode": 0
                },
                {
                    "x_": 690,
                    "y_": 48,
                    "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
                    "unknownFields": {
                        "fields": {},
                        "fieldsDescending": {}
                    },
                    "memoizedSize": -1,
                    "memoizedHashCode": 0
                },
                {
                    "x_": 631,
                    "y_": 49,
                    "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
                    "unknownFields": {
                        "fields": {},
                        "fieldsDescending": {}
                    },
                    "memoizedSize": -1,
                    "memoizedHashCode": 0
                }
            ],
            "normalizedVertices_": [],
            "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
            "unknownFields": {
                "fields": {},
                "fieldsDescending": {}
            },
            "memoizedSize": -1,
            "memoizedHashCode": 0
        },
        "locations_": [],
        "properties_": [],
        "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
        "unknownFields": {
            "fields": {},
            "fieldsDescending": {}
        },
        "memoizedSize": -1,
        "memoizedHashCode": 0
    },
    {
        "mid_": "",
        "locale_": "",
        "description_": "SI.No",
        "score_": 0,
        "confidence_": 0,
        "topicality_": 0,
        "boundingPoly_": {
            "vertices_": [
                {
                    "x_": 26,
                    "y_": 57,
                    "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
                    "unknownFields": {
                        "fields": {},
                        "fieldsDescending": {}
                    },
                    "memoizedSize": -1,
                    "memoizedHashCode": 0
                },
                {
                    "x_": 71,
                    "y_": 57,
                    "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
                    "unknownFields": {
                        "fields": {},
                        "fieldsDescending": {}
                    },
                    "memoizedSize": -1,
                    "memoizedHashCode": 0
                },
                {
                    "x_": 71,
                    "y_": 70,
                    "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
                    "unknownFields": {
                        "fields": {},
                        "fieldsDescending": {}
                    },
                    "memoizedSize": -1,
                    "memoizedHashCode": 0
                },
                {
                    "x_": 26,
                    "y_": 70,
                    "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
                    "unknownFields": {
                        "fields": {},
                        "fieldsDescending": {}
                    },
                    "memoizedSize": -1,
                    "memoizedHashCode": 0
                }
            ],
            "normalizedVertices_": [],
            "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
            "unknownFields": {
                "fields": {},
                "fieldsDescending": {}
            },
            "memoizedSize": -1,
            "memoizedHashCode": 0
        },
        "locations_": [],
        "properties_": [],
        "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
        "unknownFields": {
            "fields": {},
            "fieldsDescending": {}
        },
        "memoizedSize": -1,
        "memoizedHashCode": 0
    },
```

I have posted just few information here from the entire response due to the limitation of posting the entire data in body.

I was looking for to extract the data row by row and column but its giving the result in the given format. i see the difficulty of converting this result to row by row again. Could some please help me to achieve the expected result. Appriciate your responses!..

Apart from this, if we have any api or tool to conver the pdf to csv (including UTF-8 character set indian language pdf), it would be great....

here is the code that i am using in springboot to invoke this cloud vision api.

```
ImageContext imageContext = ImageContext.newBuilder().addLanguageHints("ta").build();
Resource imageResource = this.resourceLoader.getResource("  file:src/main/resources/Incentive.jpg");
AnnotateImageResponse response = this.cloudVisionTemplate.analyzeImage(imageResource,
        Feature.Type.DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION);
```

Comment: How about using the x and y of each word/symbol ?

Comment: Also, i'm not recognizing the structure you attached probably because it's from spring (?) but if you will take a look at the try me api, you have structured response and bounding box

Comment: @Inga890, Thank you for responding!.. yes the option that i have is to arrange these information as a row using x & y. but i was trying to see whether this api has any other option to read and provide the data in row by row. Also, if we have any another api or tool to convert UTF-8 character pdf to csv..

Comment: In the regular structure it should be page-> block->paragraph, just post your image here https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/drag-and-drop and you will get good perspective on the structure